# if condition for checking docker image on Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm pretty new with Jenkins declarative pipeline. In Jenkinsfile, I want to check if a
specific docker image is already on the machine or not. If the image is already so it just delete the old one then build the new one and if its not then its just build the new one. How can I reach this goal with declarative pipeline?

Much appreciate if you want to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete image using `sh "docker rmi -f <ImageID>"` command.
And to find the ImageID you can use `-qf` option of docker to list the imageids.
Reference example as below:

```
stage('Remove old Image') {
            steps {
                script { 
                    def imageName = "<Your image Name>"
                    env.imageName = "${imageName}"
                    def oldImageID = sh( 
                                            script: 'docker images -qf reference=\${imageName}:\${imageTag}',
                                            returnStdout: true
                                        )

                    echo "Image Name: " + "${imageName}"
                    echo "Old Image: ${oldImageID}"

                    if ( "${oldImageID}" != '' ) {
                        echo "Deleting image id: ${oldImageID}..."
                         sh "docker rmi -f ${oldImageID}"
                    } else {
                        echo "No image to delete..."
                        } 
                    }  
                }
            }
```

For info about docker images options visit  : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/

Answer (score 0):

Both building an image and pulling it from a registry are pretty inexpensive if you already have it locally.  If you're building the image, Docker's [layer caching](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) means that Docker will scan the Dockerfile and quickly conclude it already has the final image; if you're pulling it from a registry, Docker will contact the registry, get the list of layers (small), and determine it already has them all.

That means it's fine to unconditionally build/pull the image in your CI system.  If there's no work to do, it will happen quickly.

(Conversely, note that some Docker images do actually update fairly routinely; for example, the `ubuntu` base image re-releases weekly-to-monthly with updated security patches.  So there's some benefit to *always* pulling the base image in your CI system, so you're sure to get those updates.)